# Unable to display chartjs chart in Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny, chart.js

I'm working on integrating the chartjs package into my Shiny app and all is well....except....my charts will not render in the app.  They will only render in the console viewer.  I've dumbed down my code as simple as possible for assistance.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(rmarkdown)
library(htmltools)
library(zoo)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(DBI)
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(devtools)
library(chartjs)



ui <- fluidPage(
tags$body(
  plotOutput("plot"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    chartjs(mtcars, mpg, qsec, labels = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
      cjsBar
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see i'm using predefined data sets so there shouldn't be a problem with the data.  I might have some extra libraries installed as well.

Alternatively, i tried moving things around and received the same result:

```
#All libraries
 testplot <- function(){
  chartjs(mtcars, mpg, qsec, labels = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
    cjsBar
} 

ui <- fluidPage(
tags$body(
  plotOutput("plot"))


)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    testplot()
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for reasons unknown to me, i was using the wrong plot commands for output and render.  The correct solution is:

```
testplot <- function(){
  chartjs(mtcars, mpg, qsec, labels = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
    cjsBar
} 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$body(
    chartjsOutput("plot"))


)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <-renderChartjs({
    testplot()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```